# Getting the correct connection string for EF in local db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Pretty new to all this and following the instruction on a ASP.NET MVC book, so here is how my local db looks like:

[image]

And here is how my connection string looks like:

```
 <add name="EFDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True" />
```

Have I done anything wrong?

When I run the app it crashes with this message:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in Ninject.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

And also this message in the browser:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error: 



Line 11:     public class EFProductRepository:IProductsRepository
Line 12:     {
Line 13:         private EFDbContext context = new EFDbContext();
Line 14: 
Line 15:         public IQueryable<Product> Products
```

Comment: You have not properly referenced the entity framework assembly -- this is a compilation error, it has  nothing to do with the connection string -- which looks OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and update your the Entity Framework Package from NuGet, that error has nothing to do with the database.

If I recall EF6.0 had some bugs and the very same day 6.0.1 was released.

Comment: Yes updating EF fixed the error...now my next issue is it just doesn't pull the data, data is there in the DB, but its select queries return nothing. :(

Comment: From your code snippet you're using IQueryable collections, the data will not 'show' until you 'execute' the query (For debugging purposes that is). A simple test would be to add a line like var products=context.Products.ToList();  and see if you get results there.